# Let $p(z)=z^n+c_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0$ with $R=\max(1,|c_{n-1}|+\cdots+|c_0|)$. Show all the roots of $p$ are in $|z|\leq R$.

Tags: complex-analysis

By letting $f(z)=z^n$ and $g(z)=c_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0$, we want to show that $$|f(z)|\geq|g(z)|$$ on $\{z:|z|=R\}$ and apply Rouche's theorem.

Observe

Edit:

\begin{align*}
|c_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1z+c_0|&\leq |c_{n-1}||z|^{n-1}+\cdots+|c_1||z|+|c_0|\quad\text{(triangle inequality)}\\
&=|c_{n-1}|R^{n-1}+\cdots+|c_1|R+|c_0|\\
&\leq |c_{n-1}|R^{n-1}+\cdots+|c_1|R^{n-1}+|c_0|R^{n-1}\quad\text{($R\geq 1$)}\\
&=R^{n-1}(|c_{n-1}|+\cdots+|c_1|+|c_0|)\\
&\leq R^n\qquad\text{$(|c_{n-1}|+\cdots+|c_1|+|c_0|\leq R)$}\\
&=|z|^n.
\end{align*}
Thus $f+g$ and $f$ have the same number of roots inside $\{z:|z|\leq R\}$ by Rouche's. The function $z^n$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z=0$. So $p$ has $n$ zeros inside $\{z:|z|\leq R\}$ counting multiplicity.

My biggest concern is if the estimate is valid.

Comment: Not really. Note that 1) $R\ge 1$, not $\le 1$, and 2) $R^n$ could be $R^{n-1}$ in the estimation. Furthermore, does not Rouche need the strict inequality?

Comment: @A.Γ. I believe it should be. Any idea on how to get a strict inequality here?

Comment: One may e.g. consider $|z|<R+\epsilon$, $\epsilon>0$, and set $\epsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, this does not require Rouche's theorem. It suffices to show that if $z_0$ is a root and $|z_0|>1$, then $$|z_0|\leq |c_{n-1}|+\cdots +|c_0|.$$ To prove this, assume $z_0$ is a root with $|z_0|>1,$ then $$z_0^n=-(c_{n-1}z_0^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0)$$ $$\Rightarrow |z_0|^n\leq |c_{n-1}||z_0|^{n-1}+\cdots+|c_0|$$
$$\Rightarrow |z_0|^n\leq |z_0|^{n-1}(|c_{n-1}|+\cdots +|c_0|)$$
$$\Rightarrow |z_0|\leq |c_{n-1}|+\cdots +|c_0|,$$ as required.

Comment: We can also show by elementary algebra that if $|z|\ge 1+\max (|c_0|,...|c_{n-1}|)$  then $|z|^n>\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|c_iz^i|$ to obtain another result: That if $p(z)=0$ then $|z|<1+\max (|c_0|,...,|c_{n-1}|).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks. Absolutely, given the condition, this follows from $|z|^n-1=(|z|-1)(|z|^{n-1}+\cdots+1)\geq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|c_iz^i|$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The OP's bound is due to Cauchy. Do you know who is credited for the bound you mentioned?

Comment: Some other bounds: http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/~gvm/radovi/rad2.pdf